# Java List stream anyMatch returning incorrect result

Tags: java, jpa, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have a JPA class 'Project' which has a list of `'Employee'` and the `getEmployeeList()` returns the list of `Employees`.

```
public  class Project implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Employee.class)
    private List<Employee> employeeList;

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
        return this.employeeList;
    }
}

public  class Employee implements Serializable {
    @Basic
    private EmployeeType type;

    public EmployeeType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

public enum EmployeeType implements Serializable{
  EDITOR,
  AUDITOR,
  ADMIN,
  INACTIVE
}
```

I have an Employee with type 'Auditor' and when I run the following

```
for(Employee e: p.getEmployeeList()){
     if(e.getType()==EmployeeType.AUDITOR)
         found=true;
 }
```

it returns true which it should, but when I run

```
(p.getEmployeeList()).stream().anyMatch((e) -> (e.getType()==EmployeeType.AUDITOR))
```

it returns false

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: He's comparing enum variables so shouldn't it work like that ? The code seems fine to me even if it has unecessary parenthesis `p.getEmployeeList().stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getType() == EmployeeType.AUDITOR)` is ok too.

Comment: yeah your right.  I'm going to remove the comment.

Comment: Are you sure `p.getEmployeeList()` doesn't return an empty list? If it does, `found` will hold its initial value (which perhaps you initialized to true by mistake) without entering the loop at all, but anyMatch will return false.

Comment: my initial value of `found` is false, and I ran the loop and the anyMatch on the same dataset so it should return the same result.

Comment: Try tossing a `.peek(System.out::println)` into the stream before your `anyMatch()` to see what's actually being fed in.

Comment: `(p.getEmployeeList()).stream().peek(e -> System.out.println(e.getType()))` or `p.getEmployeeList().stream().forEach((Employee e) -> {
                            System.out.println(e.getType());});` does not print anything, but `p.getEmployeeList().size()` prints the correct value. And i just found out `p.getEmployeeList` returns an IndirectList and IndirectList does not have a stream function but i am not getting any error stating the function does not exist.

Comment: but if do `ArrayList<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList(p.getEmployeeList());` and call `System.out.println(employeeList.size());` ,
 `employeeList.stream().forEach((Employee e) -> System.out.println(e.getType()));` and 

`employeeList.stream().anyMatch(emp-> (emp.getType()==EmployeeType.AUDITOR));//returns true` it returns the correct value.

Comment: using  equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() insted of == could works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - change the return type to arraylist

```
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(this.employeeList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your EclipseLink version, this bug is already fixed!

Bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433075

Update to version 2.6.0 or higher: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.6.0